# Where should interfaces be defined when using the factory pattern?

Tags: go, interface, factory

I am using a factory object `FooFactory` to create instances of a type `Foo` which has some private data members. I use the factory so that an object `Bar` which creates instances of `Foo` doesn't need to provide (or even know about) these private data members: I first configure the factory with the necessary private stuff and then give `Bar` this configured factory.

I want `Bar` to use these `Foo` objects via an interface so I can mock them using `gomock` and test that `Bar` uses them correctly. From what I've read about interfaces in go, the best practise is to define the interfaces where they're used rather than where the underlying types are defined, so I have a `Fooer` interface in the same package as my `Bar` object, and `Bar` uses this `Fooer` interface wherever it expects a `Foo` (or later, a `MockFoo`).

I also want `Bar` to use the `FooFactory` via interface for the same reason, so I can mock it and assert that it creates `Foo` objects when I expect it to. And again, I define an interface in `Bar`s package `FooBuilder`, which the underlying `FooFactory` implicitly implements.

Now **the issue is** that the `FooFactory` returns concrete `Foo` objects since they are both in the same `Foo` package and shouldn't know about `Bar`'s locally defined interfaces. However, I want the `FooBuilder` to build objects of type `Fooer` rather than objects of type `Foo` because it shouldn't need to know about the underlying types. Go does not allow this since the return types differ and it says that the `FooFactory` does not implement `FooBuilder`.

Here a minimal reproduction without the package structure described above:

```
type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) FooMethod() {}

type FooFactory struct{}

func (ff *FooFactory) Build() *Foo {
    return &Foo{}
}

type Fooer interface {
    FooMethod()
}

type FooBuilder interface {
    Build() Fooer
}

func main() {
    f := &Foo{}
    ff := &FooFactory{}

    var fooer Fooer
    var fooBuilder FooBuilder

    fooer = f
    fooBuilder = ff     // << ERROR
}
```

Go complains:

```
cannot use ff (type *FooFactory) as type FooBuilder in assignment:
    *FooFactory does not implement FooBuilder (wrong type for Build method)
        have Build() *Foo
        want Build() Fooer
```

My question is essentially, am I doing this *right*? After a background in professional C++ and Java, I'm trying to embrace go's notion of implicit interface satisfaction but this just feels weird. The fact that this isn't easy to do makes me think I'm doing something wrong, but everything I read online about go's interfaces says to define interfaces close to where they're used, which is what I'm really trying to do.

Comment: To me it seems you are vastly overcomplicating things by starting your design with Factories and Mock objects in mind. Do not do that. This might be fine (or at least accepted best practice) in Java/C++/C#. E.g. if Foo and Bar live in the same package there might not be any problem with Bar knowing about Foo's internals. Do not go full monty with information hiding. Even C++ knows friends. Do not mock. Write stubs or fakes. Mocking is _not_ idiomatic in Go. Your tests live in the same package and can even inspect the internals.

Comment: If you insist on Factory and Builder: You **must** have your Factory return a Fooer. dead simple, that is how Go's type system works. No workaround here. Consider using more functions or function closures instead of objects and methods. Go objects are idiomatically built by a function NewFoo and not via fooFactory.Build. If this build process cannot be done from first principles try a function closure for NewFoo.

Answer (score 1):

### Conceptually

You're correct in your method. Though if the setup of `Foo` isn't complex, I'd drop the factory.

`Foo` and `Fooer` may or may not be in different packages. I'd start by putting them in the same package until it doesn't make sense anymore.

The way I normally set these situations up is:

```
package foo

func NewFoo() *Foo {
    return &Foo{}
}

type Foo struct{}

func (f *Foo) FooMethod() {}

type Fooer interface {
    FooMethod()
}
```

And a consumer with:

```
package bar

func FooUser(f Fooer) {
    //Do something
}
```

And putting it together with:

```
package main

import (
    "foo"
    "bar"
)

func main() {
    f := foo.NewFoo()
    bar.FooUser(f)
}
```

This way you can test the `foo` package as a unit and test the `bar` package with any struct that implements `Fooer`.

You'll find that quite a few core packages are built this way as well.

### Compiler error

The bit you're are missing is that `FooFactory` isn't actually implementing the `FooBuilder` interface.

`FooBuilder` interface declares a method that returns `Fooer` but the method signature for `FooFactory` returns a pointer to `Foo`.

```
func (ff *FooFactory) Build() *Foo
```

So you're declaring method `Build` but you're returning the wrong type, so it isn't recognized as an implementation.

To fix the error, change the signature of `Build`'s implementation to:

```
func (ff *FooFactory) Build() Fooer
```

Comment: I'm aware of the reason go complains; I'm more asking "why did I end up in this situation when I thought I was following best practises". Admittedly the code example doesn't illustrate this but the question itself does: `Foo` is in one package while `Fooer` is in another where `Foo` is meant to be used by interface (and thus mockable).

Comment: I've clarified my answer

Comment: It's considered bad practice to return a non-exported type from an exported function or method, though.

Comment: @jub0bs that makes sense. Can you cite a reference?

Comment: `golint`, in particular, will warn you about that.

Comment: `exported func Foo returns unexported type *foo.foo which can be annoying to use`
